# "C++ float vs. double Differences?"

Tags: c++

I'm looking to gain a deeper understanding of the differences between the float and double data types in C++. While I know that both are used for representing real numbers as floating-point values, I'd like to know the key distinctions between them in terms of precision and storage size.

I've reviewed C++ documentation and articles about float and double data types.

Comment: The C++ standard leaves a lot of what you're asking as implementation defined. Check your specific C++ compiler's documentation, and the header files, which define your C++ compiler's actual limits and precision.

Comment: The difference is usually precision but it is an implementation detail. `float` and `double` could be the same as far as the language is concerned.

Comment: Another difference is the `double` is the natural floating point type of C. This `1.234` is type `double`, and a `float` passed to `printf` and other variadic functions is promoted to `double`. Always use `double` unless there is a particular need to use `float`.

Comment: While implementation-defined, the implementation will choose based on the hardware. On an x86 or x86-64, `single` and `double` are surely [IEEE 754 single-precision floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) and [IEEE 754 double-precision floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) respectively.

Comment: [Floating-point types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Floating-point_types)

Comment: Important point: “both are used for representing real numbers as floating-point values” — both are used to **approximate** real numbers. Floating-point math has its own set of rules that will surprise you if you think of them as real numbers. Put your understanding of real numbers aside.